# It could be vs. it is possible

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say you were asked by an economic teacher. And it goes like this:

> Economic teacher: Do you think economic instability will continue in the future?
>
> You: It **could be**, but won't be long.

Or

> You: **It's possible**, but won't be long.

Both of them, as we all know is talking about probability, but is there any **difference** between these two?

Comment: The word *possible* doesn't necessarily relate to probability. *Possible* is also the antonym of *impossible*. (Whereas I would say that *could be* is more the antonym of *might not be*.) While the context here would seem to preclude that sense, it would still influence my decision on word choice.

Comment: Which is better between them?

Comment: I'd say, the second part "but won't be long" is crump here. Possibly because long thus refers to instability rather then its continuance. In case of "but not for long", I'd pick "possibly". Thus, "Possibly, but not for long."

Comment: I agree with @Jason – words like _likely_ and _probable_ may be related to probability, but phrases like _might happen_ and _could (possibly) happen_ are just saying the probability is not zero. Those phrases by themselves don’t give clues as to the remoteness or likelihood of the event eventually coming to pass.

Comment: I would prefer "It could *happen*..." over "It could *be*...", because you are referring to a possible occurrence involving some length of time, rather than a fixed state.